# Moving TFS CI Build def to VSTS - VSTS CI build def gets everything and builds everything

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

We are starting to migrate our old xaml build def's to VSTS web-based build def's. For each branch, we have a debug build def and a release build def. The debug build def is set up as a Continuous Integration build. As a test, I modified one source file and checked it in. The old xaml build def checked out the 1 file and seemed to have built only the project that changed (what we want and expect in a CI build). In the xaml build log I see the following:

```
<InformationField Name="Message" Value="1 file(s) were downloaded with a total size of 0.29 MB." />
```

and it ran the build in 3.3 minutes.

In the new VSTS build - I see that it does a "tf get /version:170936" and gets all the files in changeset id "170936":

```
2018-06-12T15:08:39.8409262Z Checking if artifacts directory exists: C:\BuildAgent\agent2\_work\1\a
2018-06-12T15:08:39.8409262Z Deleting artifacts directory.
2018-06-12T15:08:39.8409262Z Creating artifacts directory.
2018-06-12T15:08:39.8564882Z Checking if test results directory exists: C:\BuildAgent\agent2\_work\1\TestResults
2018-06-12T15:08:39.8564882Z Deleting test results directory.
2018-06-12T15:08:39.8564882Z Creating test results directory.
2018-06-12T15:08:39.8877401Z Starting: Get sources
2018-06-12T15:08:39.9033640Z Entering TfvcSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2018-06-12T15:08:39.9033640Z localPath=C:\BuildAgent\agent2\_work\1\s
2018-06-12T15:08:39.9033640Z clean=False
2018-06-12T15:08:39.9033640Z sourceVersion=170936
2018-06-12T15:08:39.9033640Z mappingJson={"mappings":[{"serverPath":"$/Path/To/Branch","mappingType":"map","localPath":"\\"}]}
2018-06-12T15:08:39.9033640Z Syncing repository: Project Name (TFVC)
2018-06-12T15:08:39.9033640Z workspaceName=ws_1_45
2018-06-12T15:09:06.7318304Z Workspace Name: ws_1_45;a6060273-b85e-4d4b-ac63-3fbbcafc308b
2018-06-12T15:09:06.7630780Z tf get /version:170936
2018-06-12T15:09:21.6070136Z Getting C:\BuildAgent\agent2\_work\1\s;C124440
2018-06-12T15:09:21.6070136Z Getting C:\BuildAgent\agent2\_work\1\s;C124440
2018-06-12T15:09:21.6226405Z Getting C:\BuildAgent\agent2\_work\1\s\.nuget;C158533
2018-06-12T15:09:21.6226405Z Getting C:\BuildAgent\agent2\_work\1\s\Build Scripts;C141602
2018-06-12T15:09:21.6226405Z Getting C:\BuildAgent\agent2\_work\1\s\Databases;C124440
~ 
~ The rest of branch...
~
```

and then seems to rebuild all projects taking 13.2 min to run, almost 10 minutes longer than old xaml build.

Am I missing something with the new build def? I do not have the "Clean" button checked in the VS Build task. I do have a build.clean variable but it is Blank by default - sometimes we want to clean so we just can set it to "all" at queue time.

Clicking about on the web shows the following MS VSTFS version: 15.105.25910.0

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, exactly. If it's the first run on a given build agent, it's naturally going to have to synchronize all the source code. If your steps specify to build certain projects, it's going to build all of those projects. That's the same behavior that XAML build exhibited.

Comment: The problem is - in my xaml CI build definition, in the build log I see the following throughout the log and it doesn't rebuild any projects that have not changed since the last check-in: "All outputs are up-to-date." In the new web build log - it rebuilds all the projects when I would expect to see the same thing.

Comment: Does it always occur when you queue the build several times with the same changeset?

Comment: Yes, it appears to do a complete get and you can see all the files with their corresponding Changeset ID's C{###}. When I go to the source dir, I see all files with today's date. And when I rerun the build, I see the same thing. Old xaml Build Def - only files that changed have today's date. And like I said, the old build def build takes about 3 min to run the build and the new build def takes over 13 minutes to run - which tells me it is rebuilding all projects and the old one only builds the projects that have changed - which is what is expected.

Comment: According to your description, seems the build is not  actually perform **incremental build** (the Clean option disabled, Clean = Flase), take a look at this thread [Clean the local repo on the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/vsts/pipelines/build/repository?view=vsts#clean-the-local-repo-on-the-agent-1) Are you using multiple build agents? This build may not run each time for the same build agent. Which maybe the rootcause.

Comment: Ahh, multiple build agents - I am using 4 build agents to run 8 different configurations on 4 different VM's. So I guess it is random which agent starts a specific build configuration. So does that mean you can't really run the "Multi-configuration" option to be "continuous integration" with multiple agents? Don't you need multiple agents to use the "Multi-configuration" option?

Comment: BTW- not being an "incremental build"; the Clean checkbox of the VS Build task is NOT checked, and the clean option in the Repository is set to "false"

Comment: I have not gotten back to this yet..will let you know. I've done quite a few tests with all the different options and none seem to have it only build projects that have changed. Even if nothing has changed, seems to get everything and rebuild. The only thing I haven't tried is going back to one agent, uncheck the parallel builds and let everything build sequential and then rerun on the same agent. Will see what happens. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For multiple build agents, even though you have not checked **Clean** checkbox of the VS Build task, and the clean option in the Repository is set to "false".

Since the agent is randomly picked, it may not contain your source code before.  That's why you see that TFS does a `tf get /version:170936` and gets all the files in changeset id "170936" and also build all projects.

For Multi-configuration in Options tab of build definition. Please refer the official Article: [How do I build multiple configurations for multiple platforms?](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/visual-studio-build#how-do-i-build-multiple-configurations-for-multiple-platforms)

[image]

After that, it will split configurations to multiple builds during the build.

[image]

And ow that your build definition successfully builds multiple configurations, you can go ahead and **enable parallel builds to reduce the duration/feedback time of your build**. You specify this as additional option on the **Options** page:
[image]

Take a look at this post [Building multiple configurations and/or platforms in Build 2015](https://blog.jessehouwing.nl/vsts-build-building-multiple-configuration-platform/)

To narrow down if the issue is related to multiple build agents, you could also  [send TFS build to a specific agent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2017/02/08/how-to-send-tfs-build-to-a-specific-agent-or-server/) by demand, and queue the build multiple times with `clean=false` in the same build agent, it should  have built only the project that changed(CI).

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for the detailed answer. I do have my build def setup just as you have shown. However, I just don't think you are able to do incremental builds in parallel with multiple agents. I have 8 agents on 4 different machines. When looking at the logs - I see for a particular BuildConfig|Platform, it is run on different agent every time. Is that what causes a complete rebuild? Not sure. And even though only a single project may have changed it does a complete get of everything.